# Dask Kubernetes strange behavior of adapt method

Tags: python, kubernetes, dask

I have a Dask cluster on AKS and I want to run a function `f` in parallel, but have this function run in a single process allocated in a single pod. According to the documentation on [Worker Resources](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/resources.html) I should start each worker with `dask-worker scheduler:8786 --nthreads 6 --resources "process=1"`. I need it because `f` is using multithreading internally.

```
# Example adapting up to 10 pods

from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster

cluster = KubeCluster(pod_template="pod_template.yml", deploy_mode="remote")
cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=10)
client = Client(cluster)

# for this example suppose f has no arguments
futures = [client.submit(f, resources={"process": 1}) for _ in range(5)]  # 5 execution of f (could be map but this is an example)
results = [ft.result() for ft in futures]
```

When I execute the code above, 5 worker pods are raised, but the executions of `f` are carried out in only one of these 5 and sequentially.

If instead of `adapt` method I set manually `cluster.scale(5)`, the executions of `f` **most of the time** run as I wish. I say most of the time because sometimes the behavior is similar to that of the `adapt` method. This behavior seems very strange to me.

Here is my `pod_template.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: MyCustomDockerImage
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '6', --no-dashboard, --memory-limit, 8GB, --death-timeout, '60', --resources, 'process=1']
    name: testdask
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "8"
        memory: 8G
      requests:
        cpu: "8"
        memory: 8G
  imagePullSecrets: 
    - name: acr-secret

  tolerations:
    - key: workloadpool
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "true"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
  nodeSelector:
    nodepool: workloadpool
```

Comment: would you consider changing the title of the post to something along the lines of "How do Dask worker resources work"?

Answer (score 0):

`adapt()` does not guarantee that the cluster will spawn workers to match the number of tasks, nor that tasks will be assigned to the newly spawned worker.

You can lower the `target_duration` (default `"5s"`) used to calculate the desired number of workers based on the current workload:

```py
cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=10, target_duration="1ns")
```

I found that `"1ns"` to `"500ms"` works for tasks that take at least 2 seconds.
One factor that may affect this is how long the cluster takes to spawn a worker.

But it is not guaranteed that tasks will be assigned to the newly spawned worker.
To achieve round-robin for `client.submit()`, see my original answer below.

---

*(Original answer #2, before the question was edited to include this)*

Pass `resources={'process': 1}` like the example in the documentation:

```py
futures = [client.submit(f, resources={'process': 1}) for _ in range(5)]
```

---

*(Original answer for reference)*

The built-in scheduler does not guarantee round-robin for `client.submit()`.
However, you can specify a different worker each time in `workers` argument.

Scale the cluster if needed:

```py
n = 5
if len(client.cluster.workers) < n:
    client.cluster.scale(n)
    client.wait_for_workers(n)
```

Call [`client.scatter()`](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.scatter) — documented to be round-robin if you don't pass `broadcast=True` — on dummy data, get the workers who have that data, and then specify those workers:

```py
workers = client.who_has(client.scatter([None]*n, hash=False)).values()
futures = [client.submit(f, pure=False, workers=worker) for worker in workers]
```

Comment: @Andrex Have you tried my original answer?

Comment: Using `client.wait_for_workers(n)` and then getting workers from `worker_hosts = list(client.scheduler_info()["workers"].keys())` I think could be less tricky than scattering dummy data. The problem I have is not with `scale` method, the `adapt` is the problem

Comment: @Andrex Try the newly added solution. How long do your tasks take?

Comment: @Andrex Have you tried the `target_duration="1ns"` solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this example](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/resources.html#resources-are-applied-separately-to-each-worker-process) in the Dask docs is what you're looking for and requires two steps: 1) defining resources when you set up your cluster and 2) specifying the constraints per task when you submit tasks. Since you'd like to ensure each task is run inside a separate process, you can define the resources with `dask-worker scheduler:8786 --nworkers 5 --nthreads 6 --resources "process=1"` and then use `futures = [client.submit(f, resources={'process': 1}) for _ in range(5)]` to specify the constraints per task (as @aaron mentioned). This will ensure there will be at most 5 tasks running concurrently and each task will run in a separate process.

It's also worth noting here (as explained in [here](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/resources.html#resources-are-abstract)) these resources are abstract from Dask's perspective-- you could have chosen any term so long as it's consistent across workers and clients.

Comment: executing `futures = [client.submit(f, resources={'process': 1}) for _ in range(5)]` does not work, it has the same behavior as the one I wrote in the post. I had done it according to the documentation, but I didn't write it in the post. i will edit it